# How should I add animation in this case?

Tags: wpf, winforms, helix-3d-toolkit

I've modeled using helixtoolkit which is done in a wpf user control library and hosted on ElementHost. I decided to do this because my model is fairly simple (just a stick element with lineVisual3d and bunch of small spheres).

Now I want to animate it and everything I find related to animation seems too complicated for what I'm trying to accomplish. I've seen storyboard being suggested as well as transform methods.

What I have is a 3D line connected by a bunch of points3D and I want to translate them only by a series of values at a fixed time increment.

I did this in a 2D graph using a timer for winform and even a forloop did the trick.

However, I'm not sure how to do the same for a 3D line element. I was thinking that since I have a simple structure simply redrawing it would suffice.

But my problem is I want to add a slider which acts in pretty much the same way as a video player, it will increment itself as the animation runs, I want to also be able to freeze it at any point in time and use the slider to go to any point in time much like how a video player works.

My biggest question here is how do I use a slider to control the animation. Again, this animation will simply be a bunch of values that I want to translate the stick element by(a series of points).

I've already got the values but I want to add an animation for these values at every increment while being able to control it using a slider.

--I will post any code if necessary, not posting any right now because I dont know what would help explain the question better

Answer (score 0):

You can use TranslationTransform3D and apply the transform onto the 3D Model